# Экспорт массива varbinary из MS SQL DB и конвертация его в double[] С#

Tags: c#, sql-server, byte

Добрый день! 
нужно прочесть RAWDATA из БД(формат поля в бд varbinary) и преобразовать его в массив дробных значений.

"0x126F9F210000000008282F9DEE4C0F40E6A2DB79232425C0C219114FE6EEEF3FE4BEB0188A49AE3FB17EEC274E43993FD48364ECBC3880BF1ED..." -

вот так выглядит запись в бд
после расшифровки это должно выглядеть как числа разделенные запятыми.
суть в том, что стороннее приложение записывает данные в бд, а мне надо это использовать у себя в программе. 
пробовал сначала считать его в byte[], а затем конвертировать в double[]
выводит что-то странное

```
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RawData where Test=1";
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
            byte[] ImagemByte = (byte[])dtRecord.Rows[0][1];
```

если есть идеи, как можно это сделать буду благодарен)

UPDATE:
824623678;-5,70830618553364;-4,85028588237679;0,982605405828661;0,0959905065249033;0,157348964253516;-0,022671410261855;128,66753387;186,16819
824739272;-5,70000803029416;-4,85280216514089;0,982605405828661;0,0959905065249033;0,157348964253516;-0,022671410261855;128,70104218;186,17623901....

вот так данные экспортируются из программы, в бд они хранятся только в том поле с rawdata. вот это и хотелось бы получить.

Comment: Каким именно способом закодированы данные?

Comment: Если данные закодированы "стандартным"  (IEEE 754)  способом - используйте [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) msdn. Например `BitConverter.ToDouble(ImagemByte ,0)`

Comment: `BitConverter.ToDouble(ImagemByte ,0)` Даёт около `4E-303`,  ToSingle даёт около `2E-29` так что уточните что вы ожитаете на выходе получить. Возможно ваше "что-то странное" и правда уже является правильным ответом для даного вопроса.

Comment: А как вы конвертируете `byte[]` в `double[]`?

Comment: читайте VARBINARY в MemoryStream и читайте как из обычного файла

Comment: Вы показали heх - голову, покажите ещё хвост данных. Может последовательность у вас "задом-на-перёд" хранится.

Comment: Зачем вам две учётки?

Comment: @nick_n_a первая не зарегистрирована. Евгений, подайте заявку на [объединение учетных записей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Без знания методики кодирования (кода/документации стороннего приложения) расшифровать данные нельзя — там может быть что угодно. Т.е. можно устроить гадание и, возможно, кто-нибудь и попадет в цель, но даже в этом случае нельзя будет определить точно является ли ответ правильным или нет. Тестирование стороннего приложения методом «черного ящика» на StackOverflow невыполнимо, да и не в тему это.

Answer (score 2):

Тут очень сильно зависит от того, как именно, в базу данных, записывались конкретно эти данные. Использовался стандартный `BinaryFormatter`, или какой-нибудь сторонний, или вообще самописный форматер. Если использовался стандартный `BinaryFormatter`, то чтение будет выглядеть как то так:

```
byte[] byte_arr = (byte[])dtRecord.Rows[0][1];
int len = byte_arr.Count();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byte_arr, 0, len);
var result = new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms) as double[];
```